# How to position thumbnail discord.py?

Tags: python, image, api, discord, bots

I am making a Bot in Python but when the bot sends the embed thumbnail, it is positioned on the right but I want to position it on the left.

Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def about(ctx):
   embed = discord.Embed(title="Warning",description="This command is under construction!",color=0xffff00)
   embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://i.imgur.com/s3PooTk.png',)
   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to set the position of the thumbnail with discord.py, because the [Discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object-embed-thumbnail-structure) does not offer any fields related to the embed thumbnail position. Thumbnails always appear in the top right corner of the embed, whereas [embed images](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.image) will always appear at the bottom.

Comment: Weird thing is that on Discord.js it is on the left

Comment: @MatteoAT are you sure about that? I have never seen a Discord embed with a thumbnail on the left.

Comment: I coded Bots with discord.js, so I know, thats why I wondered